# how to debug php script-in android image upload to php server using MultipartUploadRequest in android- no prints from server are seen in androd mobile

Tags: php, android, image, http, post

I am trying to upload an image from android mobile to php server. In android, I show all images in the phone, select 1, get its path and upload it to server using MultipartUploadRequest. In php script, I test the parameters are set, then copy the image to a folder and update a database. The PHP script is not working fine. Then how to debug the PHP script. I see no print(echo) messages from PHP script? I have included the require file definition and db creation part also.
CODE. PHP:

```
<?php 
 
 //importing dbDetails file 
 require_once 'dbDetails.php';
 
 //this is our upload folder 
 $upload_path = 'uploads/';
 
 //Getting the server ip 
 $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());
 
 //creating the upload url 
 $upload_url = 'https://'.$server_ip.'/AndroidImageUpload/'.$upload_path; 
 
 //response array 
 $response = array(); 
 
 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 
 //checking the required parameters from the request 
 if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){
 
 //connecting to the database 
 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');
 
 //getting name from the request 
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 
 //getting file info from the request 
 $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
 
 //getting the file extension 
 $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];
 
 //file url to store in the database 
 $file_url = $upload_url . getFileName() . '.' . $extension;
 
 //file path to upload in the server 
 $file_path = $upload_path . getFileName() . '.'. $extension; 
 echo "Hi"."<br>";
 
 //trying to save the file in the directory 
 try{
 //saving the file 
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$file_path);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `MyImages` (`id`, `url`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, '$file_url', '$name');";
 
 //adding the path and name to database 
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 
 //filling response array with values 
 $response['error'] = false; 
 $response['url'] = $file_url; 
 $response['name'] = $name;
 }
 //if some error occurred 
 }catch(Exception $e){
 $response['error']=true;
 $response['message']=$e->getMessage();
 }
 //displaying the response 
 echo json_encode($response);
 
 //closing the connection 
 mysqli_close($con);
 }else{
 $response['error']=true;
 $response['message']='Please choose a file';
 }
 }
 
 
 //We are generating the file name 
 //so this method will return a file name for the image to be upload 

 function getFileName(){
 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');
 $sql = "SELECT max(id) as id FROM MyImages";
 $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
 
 mysqli_close($con);
 if($result['id']==null)
 return 1; 
 else 
 return ++$result['id']; 
 }
 

?>
```

CODE.Android:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    //private static final java.util.UUID UUID = ;

    private Button buttonChoose;
    private Button buttonUpload;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private EditText editText;
    private EditText imageName;
    private EditText imagePath;
    private CheckBox displayNotification;
    private CheckBox autoDeleteUploadedFiles;
    private CheckBox autoClearOnSuccess;
    private CheckBox fixedLengthStreamingMode;
    private CheckBox useUtf8;

    //Image request code
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    //storage permission code
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;

    //Bitmap to get image from gallery
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    //Uri to store the image uri
    private Uri filePath;

    private String path;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Requesting storage permission
        requestStoragePermission();

        //Initializing views
        buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
        buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        imageName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editImageName);
        imagePath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editImagePath);

        displayNotification = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.displayNotification);
        autoDeleteUploadedFiles = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.autoDeleteUploadedFiles);
        autoClearOnSuccess = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.autoClearOnSuccess);
        fixedLengthStreamingMode = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.fixedLengthStreamingMode);
        useUtf8 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.useUtf8);

        //Setting clicklistener
        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return;

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission
        }
        //And finally ask for the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //Checking the request code of our request
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {

            //If permission is granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Displaying a toast
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonChoose) {
            showFileChooser();
        }
        if (v == buttonUpload) {
            path = getPath(filePath);
            imagePath.setText(path);
            showImage();
            uploadMultipart();
        }
    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        imageName.setText("editText.getText().toString().trim()");
        imagePath.setText(editText.getText().toString().trim());
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();

        }
    }

    private void uploadMultipart() {
        String name = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        imageName.setText(name);


        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                    .setMethod("POST")
                    //.setBearerAuth(token)
                    .addHeader("User-Agent", getString(R.string.app_name) + "/" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
                    //.addParameter("privacy", String.valueOf(idPrivacy))
                    //.addParameter("nsfw", "false")
                    .addParameter("name", name)
                    .addParameter("commentsEnabled", "true")
                    .addParameter("downloadEnabled", "true")
                    .addParameter("waitTranscoding", "true")
                    //.addParameter("channelId", idChannel)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image")
                    .setNotificationConfig(getNotificationConfig(name))
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload();
            imageName.setText("complete");

        } /*catch(IllegalArgumentException exc) {
            imageName.setText("ill");
        }*/ catch (Exception exc) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            imageName.setText("exc");
        }
    }

    private UploadNotificationConfig getNotificationConfig(String filename) {
        if (!displayNotification.isChecked()) return null;

        return new UploadNotificationConfig()
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_upload)
                .setCompletedIcon(R.drawable.ic_upload_success)
                .setErrorIcon(R.drawable.ic_upload_error)
                .setTitle(filename)
                .setInProgressMessage("getString(R.string.uploading)")
                .setCompletedMessage("getString(R.string.upload_success)")
                .setErrorMessage("getString(R.string.upload_error)")
                .setAutoClearOnSuccess(autoClearOnSuccess.isChecked())
                .setClickIntent(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class))
                .setClearOnAction(true)
                .setRingToneEnabled(true);
    }

    private String getPath(Uri uri) {
        return getPath4(uri);
    }

    private String getPath1(Uri uri) {
        File file = new File(uri.getPath());//create path from uri
        String path = file.getPath();
        return path;
    }
    private String getPath2(Uri uri) {
        File file = new File(uri.getPath());//create path from uri
        final String[] split = file.getPath().split(":");//split the path.
        String path = split[1];
        return path;
    }
    private String getPath3(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri,  proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
    private String getPath4(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();

        return path;
    }
    private void showImage(){
        show(2);
    }
    private void show(int i){
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
                showImgFromBitmap();
                break;
            case 2:
                showImgFromFilePath();
                break;
            default:
                showImgFromBitmap();
                break;
        }
    }
    private void showImgFromBitmap() {
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void showImgFromFilePath() {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
    public class Constants {
        public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "https://swulj.000webhostapp.com/upload.php";
        public static final String IMAGES_URL = "https://swulj.000webhostapp.com/getImages.php";
    }
}
```

CODE.dbDetails.php:

```
<?php 
 define('HOST','localhost');
 define('USER','userName');
 define('PASS','Pass');
 define('DB','db_name');
 ?>
```

creating db.CODE.image_db.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "userName";
$password = "Pass";

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$w = "USE db_name";

if ($conn->query($w) === TRUE) 
{
    //echo "database used successfully". "<br>";
} else
{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


 $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyImages (id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, url VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY(id))";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($res)
    {
    echo "New table created successfully". "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error. "<br>";
    }







$conn->close();


ob_flush();
ob_end_clean();

?>
```

I changed

```
new MultipartUploadRequest(this, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                        .setMethod("POST")
                        //.setBearerAuth(token)
                        .addHeader("User-Agent", getString(R.string.app_name) + "/" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
                        //.addParameter("privacy", String.valueOf(idPrivacy))
                        //.addParameter("nsfw", "false")
                        .addParameter("name", name)
                        .addParameter("commentsEnabled", "true")
                        .addParameter("downloadEnabled", "true")
                        .addParameter("waitTranscoding", "true")
                        //.addParameter("channelId", idChannel)
                        .addFileToUpload(path, "image")
                        .setNotificationConfig(getNotificationConfig(name))
                        .setMaxRetries(2)
                        .startUpload();
                imageName.setText("complete");
    
            }
```

to

```
new MultipartUploadRequest(this, Constants.TEST_URL)
                        .setMethod("POST")
                        //.setBearerAuth(token)
                        .addHeader("User-Agent", getString(R.string.app_name) + "/" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
                        //.addParameter("privacy", String.valueOf(idPrivacy))
                        //.addParameter("nsfw", "false")
                        .addParameter("name", name)
                        .addParameter("commentsEnabled", "true")
                        .addParameter("downloadEnabled", "true")
                        .addParameter("waitTranscoding", "true")
                        //.addParameter("channelId", idChannel)
                        .addFileToUpload(path, "image")
                        .setNotificationConfig(getNotificationConfig(name))
                        .setMaxRetries(2)
                        .startUpload();
                imageName.setText("complete");
    
            }
```

where

```
Constants.TEST_URL = "https://swulj.000webhostapp.com/image_db.php";
```

When I execute the url in Browser, new table is created, but when I run the android code, new table is not created. It indicates that MultipartUploadRequest is not properly formed and it does not execute the php script. But there is no exception. Can somebody help?

Comment: I wonder why you create a variable $upload_url. I also wonder that you mess around with a database if you do not even get some echo() back. Remove all from php script and just echo a string. Once you can receive the string you could echo back some parameters. Step by step add back other code.

Comment: Many people also test their scrips with Postman from Google.

Comment: _"I see no print(echo) messages from PHP script?"_ - well where would you _expect_ to see them? Your Android application is the client here in this scenario - so it would be its responsibility, to display whatever output the PHP script might have returned. Did you implement anything in that regard ...? You can of course also write your debug outputs to a file on the server instead of echo-ing them (`error_log`, `file_put_contents`), and then check in there afterwards.